# Using multiple forms in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four forms (`MainForm`, `Landed`, `Apartment`, `Condominium`) in one HTML page.

```
<body>

        <form name="MainForm" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="Landed">Landed
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="Apartment">Apartment
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="Condominium">Condominium
        </form>

        <form name="Landed" method="post"> </form>

        <form name="Apartment" method="post"></form>

        <form name="Condominium" method="post"></form>
</body>
```

`MainForm` has three radio buttons. If `Landed` radio button is pressed, the `Landed` form will be loaded together with `MainForm`. Or other radio buttons are selected, their respective forms are loaded. Before any selection is made, all forms are hidden. Then display only once a radio button is pressed.
What could be the best approach for this? I tried and all forms are loaded altogether.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'loaded'? Do you mean that you want to get the HTML for them via AJAX, or just that they will be shown/hidden based on the selected option in `#MainForm`? Also note that your HTML is invalid - you cannot have elements outside of the `<body>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just want forms are shown/hidden based on the selected option of radio buttons in #MainForm. Yes I know, I just want to show for example.

Comment: @batuman: If you use a lot of html for a web-application you max be interested in AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are doing is showing/hiding the form based on the chosen radio button, you can use `show` and `hide` based on the `id` attributes of the `form` elements, like this:

```
<form id="mainform" name="mainform" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="landed">Landed
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="apartment">Apartment
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="condominium">Condominium
</form>

<form id="landed" name="landed" method="post">
    Landed form
</form>

<form id="apartment" name="apartment" method="post">
    Apartment form
</form>

<form id="condominium" name="condominium" method="post">
    Condominium form
</form>
```

```js
$('#mainform input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('form:not(#mainform)').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bt3440w0/)